# reversegeocoder autorelease issue

Tags: ios, autorelease, mkreversegeocoder

I'm learning to use the mkreversegeocoder classes and have got it working using the following three lines of code and implementing the didFindPlacemark method.

```
geoCoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:[u coordinate]];
[geoCoder setDelegate:self];
[geoCoder start];
```

The above works fine, however... in trying to improve my app by thinking about managing memory and resources, i am trying to add an autorelease the geoCoder allocation as such:

```
geoCoder = [[[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:[u coordinate]] autorelease];
```

The above pattern is used by apple in their documentation so it seems like the right thing to do. However, when I add the autorelease, the didFindPlacemark method never gets called. It's as if the autorelease releases the geoCoder object immediately.

The geoCoder object is declared as an ivar, so it should work. the apple example using this pattern works so the problem must be with my implementation, but i cannot work out where i am going wrong.

i would appreciate anyone input as to whats happening and how i can get this going.

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined a retain property for `geoCoder` like in the Apple sample app CurrentAddress?

In their sample app, the geocoder is set using the *property accessor* otherwise the autorelease will release the ivar when you exit the method.

Change that line to:

```
self.geoCoder = [[[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWith...] autorelease];
```

Also be sure to release it in `dealloc`:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [geoCoder release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for this, it was the exact answer I needed :-) I wasn't using the property accessor. i'm still new at this so forgot that there was nothing that was retaining the reference to the object before the current event loop processed.